# Implementing push notification using chrome in Django

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

I have learned to implement push notifications for a Web Application using chrome https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en  and successfully ran the sample code mentioned in the blog.

Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate the success with Django. It never goes into the ready method of the service worker,(**navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then**) ie, the service worker is never ready.

As per http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/

> One subtlety with the register method is the location of the service
>   worker file. You'll notice in this case that the service worker file
>   is at the root of the domain. This means that the service worker's
>   scope will be the entire origin. In other words, this service worker
>   will receive fetch events for everything on this domain. If we
>   register the service worker file at /example/sw.js, then the service
>   worker would only see fetch events for pages whose URL starts with
>   /example/ (i.e. /example/page1/, /example/page2/).

In Django, how to put a JS a file under root of the application? Currently,scope of the service worker is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ (When I use chrome://serviceworker-internals/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow this method...

- put the `sw.js` file in `template` folder
- configure view to serve as static file

  ```
  #urls
  url(r'^sw(.*.js)$', views.sw_js, name='sw_js'),

  #views
  from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
  from django.template.loader import get_template
  @never_cache
  def sw_js(request, js):
      template = get_template('sw.js')
      html = template.render()
      return HttpResponse(html, content_type="application/x-javascript")
  ```

Comment: I have done what you said but it gives me the following error.

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.

Comment: Thank you :) You saved my day :)

Comment: hey have you got complete tutorial on setting up `Django` with sw.js

Comment: @KostadinSlavov Do you mean the blog like tutorial ?

Comment: @RajaSimon yeah but for django i just don't get it how it works... 2nd day on this and still cant get it

Comment: But I haven't done that part in a while. Can you provide me a hint where you suspect the problem. DM me on twitter. I will take look.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the accepted answer, but shorter:

- Place `service_worker.js` in root of the `template` folder.
- Add to your routings:

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from django.views.generic import TemplateView

  urlpatterns = [
      # Other urls
      url(r'^service_worker(.*.js)$',
          TemplateView.as_view(template_name='service_worker.js', 
              content_type='application/x-javascript'))
      ]
  ```

---

**Update**:  I ended up needing to pass authentication credentials to the `service_worker.js` file, so this was my **final** route:

```
url(r'^service_worker(.*.js)(?:/(?P<params>[a-zA-Z]+)/)?', 
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='service_worker.js', content_type='application/x-javascript'))
```

This allows passing parameters like so: `domainbase.com/service_worker.js?foo=bar...`

The javascript to then access the params is:

```
var url_params = location.search.substring(1);
console.log(url_params);
 => "foo=bar..."
```